# Show global faces message only in first h:messages component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, message

I have two global message components in one JSF page:

This

```
 <h:messages id="msg1" layout="table" globalOnly="true" showDetail="true" showSummary="false"/>
```

And this:

```
<h:messages id="msg2" layout="table" globalOnly="true" showSummary="true" showDetail="true"/>
```

The first one is initiate here:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "", "No result"));
```

And second message initiated here:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "", "Reset problem"));
```

But when `msg1` is invoked, it's message value displays in `msg2` too.

How can I avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preface: I'll assume that replacing `globalOnly="true"` by `for="someClientId"` and `addMessage("someClientId", message)` was already considered and apparently not applicable in your specific case for some reason, the solution would otherwise have been very obvious.

---

Set `redisplay` attribute to `false` on the last message component.

```
<h:messages ... redisplay="false">
```

Then it won't redisplay messages which are already displayed before in another message component. I only wonder if you can't better finetune the ajax update/render to reference only a specific message component.